# How to get value of textbox of editorfor in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

My code in textbox is this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowNewProfessionalWindow", "UpdateOrganizationUID"))
```

{
      @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Org_UID)

```
 <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="SubmitQuery()" class="login-button" />
```

}

```
function SubmitQuery() {

                var txtOrg_UID = $('#Org_UID').val();


                });
   }
```

Comment: What HTML is getting generated for the `Org_UID` field? Post that as an edit to the question. Further, **what's happening now with `$('#Org_UID').val()`**?

Comment: 1st when I submit it goes to ShowNewProfessionalWindow action result then when going to the SubmitQuery() query function then the $('#Org_UID').val(); has no value.

Answer (score 0):

you can just replace the editor for to textboxfor cause editorfor will not support any html attribute

Hope this will work !!

Answer (score 0):

You can add new id attribute, for example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Org_UID, new {id="Org_UID"})
```

Comment: You could do that, but it would mess up the automated data binding server-side on the `POST` back.